# Why is Ajax not getting the data from the table and displaying it?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, web-services, jquery

I have Get function is PHP which works

```
`// retreive all the movies
    function movies_get() {
    $this->load->database();
    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM movies;';
    $query = $this->db->query($sql);
    $data = $query->result();
    $this->response($data, 200);
    }`
```

http://creative.coventry.ac.uk/~4078078/moviereviews/v1.0/index.php/movie/movies
In apigee I get this result or this link:

```
`{
    "id": "1",
    "Title": "Anna Karenina",
    "Director": "Joe Wright",
    "cast": "Keira Knightley Jude Law Arron Taylor-Johnson",
    "genre": "Drama"
  },`
```

I am trying to work on AJAX to get the titles of the movies to display on the #movies page.
and this is my code, but what it doesn't work, I really can't figure out the error , I am new to AJAX but I have written this code, what is the error, Could it be that i am asking to display titles but it is displaying more than just the title?

```
function Get() {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://creative.coventry.ac.uk/~4078078/moviereviews/v1.0/index.php/movie/movies',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
                $.each(data.movie, function (i, id) {
                    $('#movies').append('<li> <a href="" data-transition="slide"   onclick="Getmovies(' + movies.id + ')">' + movies.Title + '<div class="ui-li-count">' + movies.records + '</div></a><li>');
                });
                $.mobile.changePage("#movies"); //show the results page

                $('#home').listview('refresh');
            },
            //error: function (response) {
            //var r = jQuery.parseJSON(response.responseText);
            //alert("Message: " + r.Message);
            //}
        }

        )
    };
```

Answer (score 1):

The response returned by AJAX (url: http://creative.coventry.ac.uk/~4078078/moviereviews/v1.0/index.php/movie/movies) is itself an array. So, you should iterate over 'data' instead of 'data.movie'. You can update your code as follows:

```
    $(data.movie).each(function(i,movie){
        $('#movies').append('<li> <a href="" data-transition="slide"   onclick="Getmovies('+movie.id+')">'+movie.Title+'<div class="ui-li-count">'+movie.records+'</div></a><li>');
    });
```

Comment: That didn't work, in my HTML do I need to do anything there may be? at the moment, it shows header, in content t has listview

Comment: I think the problem might be 'movie.records'. The json returned for the link does not have any field with name 'records'. So, either don't print movie.records or update the PHP script to send field with name 'records'.